# Hostlistener giving wrong values of nativeelement.value and click event

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning Angular 4 and creating autocomplete application

HTML:

```
 <form novalidate [formGroup] ="formG">
 <input type="text" formGroupName="formCont" id="searText" class="searchBox">
 </form>
 <div class="seracDropDown" *ngIf = "showDropDown">
 </div>
```

AppComponent:

```
import { Component, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef)
  { }
  showDropDown: boolean = false;
  formG = new FormGroup({
    formCont: new FormControl()
  })

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClickCalled(target) {
    if (target.id == "searText") {
      this.showDropDown = true;
    }
    else {
      this.showDropDown = false;
    }
  }

  @HostListener("keyup", ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(ev) {
    var str: string;
    if (ev.target.id == "searText") {
      str = this._el.nativeElement.value;
      console.log(str);
    }
  }
}
```

So if clicked in the `textbox` a `dropdown` will come which will go away clicking on anywhere on the document. Which is handled by the click `hostlistener` and the `keyup` `hostlistener` is for the value entered in the `textbox` , Now I am facing two issues.

1) On clicking in the `textbox` is showing but on clicking anywhere else it's not closing.

2) On entering any value in the text box `console.log(str);` prints `undefined`.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `click` use `document:click` and use `ev.target.value` instead of `this._el.nativeElement.value`.

Use them like following way:

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  onClickCalled(target) {   
    if (target.id == "searText") {
      this.showDropDown = true;
    }
    else {
      this.showDropDown = false;
    }
  }


  @HostListener("keyup", ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(ev) {  
    var str: string;
    if (ev.target.id == "searText") {
      str = ev.target.value;
      console.log(str);
    }
  }
```

<kbd>[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqfnkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)</kbd>

Hope this will help you!

Comment: That did help , but can you please tell me why ElementRef did not work ?

Comment: `this._el.nativeElement.value` don't know the target value when the `keyup` event fire on that input element.

Comment: Hi Coder ,

I am again facing some issue here is the link for the new problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378798/autocomplete-application-is-not-working , could you have a look into it?