# Autocomplete application is not working

Tags: angular

I am learning angular 4 , and for hands on I am creating the autocomplete application.

```html
<form novalidate [formGroup] ="formG">
<input type="text" formGroupName="formCont" id="searText" class="searchBox">
</form>
<div class="seracDropDown" *ngIf = "showDropDown">
<div class="dropDownContent" *ngFor="let obj of arr" (click)="setVal(obj)">
    {{obj}}
</div>
</div>
```

Logical code is :

```typescript
import {Component,HostListener, ElementRef,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {AppObjComponent} from './app.obj'
@Component({
 selector : "app-root",
 templateUrl : './app.component.html',
styleUrls : ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent{
@ViewChild('searText') textVal; 
objApp : any;
arr :any;
arr1 = [];
constructor(private _el:ElementRef,private appObj : AppObjComponent)
{
this.objApp = this.appObj.obj;
}  
showDropDown : boolean = false;

formG = new FormGroup({
formCont : new FormControl()
})

@HostListener('document:click',['$event.target'])
onClickCalled(target){
if(target.id =="searText")
{
 this.showDropDown = true;
 }
 else
 {
 console.log("I am here");
 this.showDropDown = false;
 }
 }

 @HostListener("keyup",['$event'])
 onKeyUp(ev)
 {
  var str :string; 
  let i =0;
  if(ev.target.id=="searText")
  {
  str = ev.target.value;
  this.arr = this.funcArray(str);
  console.log(this.arr[i]);
  i++;
  }
  }

  funcArray(str:string) : any
  {
  let i=0;
  let arr =[];
  let arr1 =[];
  this.objApp.forEach(element => {
   console.log(element);
   if(element.toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase()))
   {
  console.log("hello");
  arr[i]=element;
  i++;
  return arr;
  }
  else{
  return arr1;
  }
 });
 }

setVal(obj){
console.log(obj);
 this.textVal.nativeElement.value = obj;
}
}
```

Now I am facing two problems , in the drop down When I click on any value the text should get that. 
1) I am using `viewchild` on the input text and later through `setval` I am trying to set the value of the text which has been selected. It's throwing:

> error cannot read undefined property .

2) In the `keyup` `hostlistener` I am sending the entered characters to the `funcArray` function and compare those characters with the starting of the values of `foreach` which is of string  type. And return the array if it matches otherwise returns empty array. But it is also throwing error saying:

> can not read property of 0.

Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to change the `formGroupName="formCont"` to `formControlName="formCont"` and look like this:

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="formCont" name="searchText" id="searText" class="searchBox">
```

And change your `setVal()` function like below:

```typescript
setVal(obj) {
    this.formG.controls.formCont.setValue(obj);
}
```

These steps will fix your first problem.

To fix second one you have to check if values are exist in `this.arr` before you are going to read value from it like below:

```typescript
  this.arr = this.funcArray(str);
  if (this.arr.length > 0){
      console.log(this.arr[i]);
  }
```

---

**Note:**

According to their [DOC](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

> You can use `ViewChild` to get the first element or the directive
>   matching the selector from the view DOM.

If you need to use `@ViewChild` you could use template reference variable like below:

```html
 <input #searchInput type="text" formControlName="formCont" name="searchText" id="searText" class="searchBox">
```

Then in component use it like this:

```typescript
@ViewChild('searchInput') textVal;
```

You could see this <kbd>[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fixed-stack-issue-huho1n?file=src/app/app.component.ts)</kbd>

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Why can't I use viewchild  to set the value , do I always have to use a form control to wok with it as in other examples I have people using viewchild on the element's id ?

Comment: @sona mondal I updated the answer with little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I am using viewchild on the input text and later through setval I
>   am trying to set the value of the text which has been selected. It's
>   throwing error cannot read undefined property

You should use template variable to get access to that input, so your code should look like this:

`<input type="text" formGroupName="formCont" id="searText" class="searchBox" #searText>`

> 2) In the keyup hostlistener I am sending the entered characters to
>   the funcArray function and compare those characters with the starting
>   of the values of foreach which is of string type. And return the array
>   if it matches otherwise returns empty array. But it is also throwing
>   error saying can not read property of 0.

You could bind keyup event straight to the input, e.g.

`<input (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" type="text" formGroupName="formCont" id="searText" class="searchBox" #searText>`

This should work

Comment: I had used template variable even that is not working